# ModX Evo Manager - Documents searching and filtering

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

Is there any way to search and filter documents by some tags or TV in ModX Evo Manager?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it by default. Tags, TV's are stored in other DB table, than resources so You have to find some plugin, but i'm not sure it is possible any way in MODx document tree. 
Other way is to create Custom Manager Page with list of filtered resources. Look at [here](http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/advanced-development/custom-manager-pages) to get some more informations.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for resources (documents) in MODX Evo manager via the menu after logging in: **Site > Search**. That lets you search by ID, template, pagetitle, longtitle, alias or content. (Also by URL, but I'm not sure what input is expected there). Matching resources are listed, with their IDs and links to view them.